# Display Push message in notification center when device is locked

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

How can I display Push message (summary) in iOS Notification center while the device is locked ?

Does the App publishes messages to Notification center (what if the app is not running), or does the system takes care of it automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is user's settings. It can be configured in `Settings App > Notification Center > ( Your APNS registered App ) > Show in Lock Screen`.

In you App's `programming logic`, you **cannot control** whether it shows in Lock screen or not.

Comment: Alert style is 'Alerts', all other options are turned on (including Show in Notification Center and Show on Lock Screen). But still the APNS message is not getting displayed in the Notification Center while the device is in locked state. Any idea what I am missing ?

Comment: APNS Payload has maximum size. Does your message really delivered to the device?

Comment: Yes the messages is being delivered. I can see the message if the App is running (on foreground). But if the app is killed/in-background, I only hear sound/vibration.

Comment: k, found the issue. Problem was with the APNS JSON message format that I had created. Thanks to everyone for helping!